# can this work? insert into with select...i have my own value and want to take some data from other table

Tags: mysql, insert

can this work? insert into with select...i have my own value and want to take some data from other table

well, i haven't try this, still thinking about this

```
insert into table1(number,       name, inventory)
                      |               |
             --my own values   --from table2 --> row 1
             --my own values   --from table2 --> row 2
```

and i want a result like this

```
table1
number  | name   |  inventory
Z001    | desk   |  50
Z002    | chair  |  100
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. [Insert select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
insert into table1 (number, name, inventory) 
select number,  name, inventory from table2
```

If you're talking about restricting to literally rows 1 and 2:

```
insert into table1 (number, name, inventory) 
select number,  name, inventory from table2
where number = 'Z001' or number = 'Z002'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in one query. to insert your own values into a table you would use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table1(number) VALUES (myValue)
```

And to insert values from another table you would use a different syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table1(name, inventory) 
   SELECT row1, row2 FROM table2
```

So you see, you cannot mix the two. I suggest doing the second INSERT first for name and inventory, than using UPDATE to insert the number.
**First:**

```
INSERT INTO table1(name, inventory) 
   SELECT row1, row2 FROM table2
```

**than:**

```
UPDATE table1
SET number = myValue
```

if **myValue** is a set of values, and not just one value, use a loop that repeats this update with an added WHERE, and **myValue** as a variable that changes to the next value in your set. Since I don't know on what you're using SQL, I can't tell you how to do the loop. Good luck!